# Insert page breaks for Meta Data block header and TOC for Pandoc

Tags: latex, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm struggling to get line breaks in exported `pdf` files with Pandoc.

I have the following `markdown`:

```
---
title: "Linux assignment"
subtitle: "Very hard"
author: Max
geometry: margin=2cm
output: pdf_document
---

# Introduction
Hello

This is some `code`

\pagebreak

# Technical sections

\pagebreak
```

I export the input to `pdf` with this command:

```
pandoc task.md -f markdown \
    --toc \
    --metadata date="`date +%D`" \
    -s -o test1.pdf \
```

The output looks like this:

[image]
The explicit `\pagebreak` works as they should. But I want page breaks between the header and the TOC, and between the TOC and the content, which is not what I achieve.

I've read that templates can be adapted. The `pandoc -D latex` template is quite massive, and I've tried to introduce page break, without success.

Comment: What do you mean with "linebreaks between the header and the TOC"? Each starts in a new line by default.

Comment: I mean page breaks, fixed the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert the toc manually, you can control if there should be pagebreaks around it:

```
---
title: "Linux assignment"
subtitle: "Very hard"
author: Max
geometry: margin=2cm
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: false
---

\pagebreak
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak

# Introduction
Hello

This is some `code`

\pagebreak

# Technical sections

\pagebreak
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer. I ended up opting for the `LaTeX` template [Eisvogel](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template) as I had some more small stuff that I wanted a bit more custom.